# Policy data structure on my compiler is not working

Tags: c++, data-structures, compiler-errors

I want to use a policy based data structure but my compiler keeps on giving me errors.

Here is what im using in my code:

```
#include <ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp>
#include <ext/pb_ds/tree_policy.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace __gnu_pbds;
template <typename T> using oset = tree<T, null_type, less<T>, rb_tree_tag, tree_order_statistics_node_update>;
```

Here are the error messages I recieve:

```
fatal error: 
      'ext/typelist.h' file not found
#include <ext/typelist.h>
```

and

```
error: function-like macro
      '__GLIBC_PREREQ' is not defined
#if __GLIBC_PREREQ(2,15) && defined(_GNU_SOURCE)
```

I've tried replacing the files over and over again but it keeps on telling me to continuously add new files that my computer does not have. I am using VS Code on a mac. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The macro  __GLIBC_PREREQ is defined in `<cstdlib>` , it is not to be guaranteed to be included by default. It looks like you had omitted some vital header or the implementations of those headers don't include `<cstdlib>`

PBDS requirec gcc, saying that you use VSCode IDE doesn't tell what compiler you're using.